# Sticky sidebar on waypoints infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'm making a webpage with a list of infinite scrollable items, and a sidebar using sticky sidebar on the right. The issue is the sidebar stops sticking when scrolling for dynamically loaded infinite items. How do i have it stick to these new items as well

```
{% extends 'mainnew.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
 <main>
     <hr>
         <div class="mt-lg-12 mb-lg-14 mb-8">
            <!-- container -->
            <div class="container">
               <!-- row -->
               <div class="row">
                  <!-- col -->
                  {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
                  <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-8 col-md-12 mb-6 mb-md-0">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                           <div class="row align-items-center mb-6">
                            <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-9 col-8">
                                <div class="mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                                    {% if selected_stores %}
                                        <h3 class="mb-1" style="display: inline-block;">Parduotuvėse: 
                                            {% for store in selected_stores %}
                                                {{ store }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </h3>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if search_name %}
                                        <h3 class="mb-1" style="display: inline-block;">Rezultatai: {{ search_name }}</h3>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <h3 class="mb-1" style="display: inline-block;">Rezultatai: visi</h3>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           </div>
                            <div class="row row-cols-xl-4 row-cols-lg-3 g-4 infinite-container ">
                                {% for item in items %}
                                    <div class="col infinite-item">
                                        <div class="mb-6 product-content">
                                            <div class="card card-product mb-4 ">
                                                <div class="card-body text-center py-8">
                                                    <!-- img -->
                                                    <a href="{{ item.url }}">
                                                        <img src="{{ item.image_url }}"
                                                             alt="Item Image"
                                                             class="mb-3"
                                                             style="width: 120px; height: 120px; object-fit: contain;">
                                                    </a>
                                                    <!-- text -->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <span class="badge rounded-pill {% if item.store.name == 'Iki' %}bg-success{% elif item.store.name == 'Rimi' %}bg-danger{% elif item.store.name == 'Maxima' %}bg-info{% elif item.store.name == 'Lidl' %}bg-info-light{% endif %}">{{ item.store.name }}</span>
                                                {% if item.discount_percentage %}
                                                <span class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill">-{{ item.discount_percentage }}%</span>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                <h2 class="mt-3 fs-6"><a href="#" class="text-inherit">{{ item.name }}</a></h2>
                                                <div>
                                                    <span class="text-dark fs-5 fw-bold">{{ item.discount_price }}</span>
                                                    {% if item.regular_price %}
                                                    <span class="text-decoration-line-through text-muted">{{ item.regular_price }}</span>
                                                    {% endif %}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    {% if items.has_next %}
                                        <a class="infinite-more-link" href="{% url 'search' %}?page={{ items.next_page_number }}">more</a>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </main>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.7.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/infinite.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
          element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

the sidebar follows the div with product-content class. i think i need to somehow update this class tag, but i'm unsure of how to do it